# How do you fix a sinple_form input tag to manually typing an integer instead of having a up/down clicking icon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have an input that has the data type of an integer. When I created a form for that attribute, the simple_form gem gives me a up/down click icon thingy on the right hand side of the input box.

I would like to make this a regular input box, which I can manually type in integers.

Below is what I currently have.

```
<%= f.input :price %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple form detects the field type based on the data type of the field in display. Since what you have may be numaric in nature you will get the numeric input.

You can override this using the `as` option and requesting it to be a `text`. Here is how to do it.

```
<%= f.input :price, as: :text %>
```

But if you are concerned about the decimal places and arrow increment/decrement, you can configure it to lets say go cent by cent with some thing like

```
<%= f.input :price, input_html: { increment: '0.01' } %>
```